# Strong Law of Large Numbers for Stationary Process

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

In the text, "Function Analysis" by Stein and Shakarchi volume 4, there is a proof for the strong law for a sequence of I.I.D. random variables $\{f_n\}$ that involves showing that a shift $\tau$ defined on a product space $Y$ is both measure-preserving and ergodic.

Specifically, $Y = R^\infty = \prod_{j = 0}^\infty R_j$ where each $R_j = \mathbb{R}$ with $m^*$ the corresponding product measure of $\mu$, the common distribution function of $\{f_n\}$. Also, the shift $\tau:Y \to Y$ is given by $\tau(y) = (y_{n + 1})_{n = 0}^\infty$, if $y = (y_n)_{n = 0}^\infty$.

The theorem was proven by defining $\{g_n\}$ to be the coordinate functions on $Y$.

I'm having trouble with the case where instead of $\{f_n\}$ being I.I.D., it is stationary. That is, for every $N$, the joint probability distribution of $f_r, f_{r + 1}, \dots, f_{N + r}$ is independent of $r$. The text says consider the probability space $Y$ as constructed from above, and then to show that whenever ${f_n}$ is a stationary process, then it has the same joint distribution as the sequence ${g_0(\tau^n(y))}$, where $g_0$ is a suitable function on $Y$. However, I am unsure about how to go about defining such a $g_0$.

This is a problem that a professor and I have been puzzled with for a while during our independent study together. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

$g_0$ is simply the first projection: $g_0(y_0,y_1,y_2,...)=y_0$. Use statinarity to show that $(f_n)$ and $(g_0(\tau^{n}(y))$ have the same finite dimensional distribution. That also implies that they induce the same probability measure on $Y$.